# CarbonPeriod is not returning incomplete days

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I want to split into days:

```
2021-03-23T00:00:00Z
2021-03-24T23:00:00Z
```

Which represent 1 day and 1 hour.

If I try to make a carbon period with those:

```
$periods = CarbonPeriod::create($start, "1 day", $end);
```

It will return:

```
[0] = 2021-03-23T00:00:00Z
[1] = 2021-03-24T00:00:00Z
```

And I will lose 1 hour.

How should I do to make it return:

```
[0] = 2021-03-23T00:00:00Z
[1] = 2021-03-24T00:00:00Z
[2] = 2021-03-24T00:23:00Z
```

Or if it is not possible, at least:

```
[0] = 2021-03-23T00:00:00Z
[1] = 2021-03-24T00:00:00Z
[2] = 2021-03-25T00:00:00Z
```

Comment: what is the problem with [0] = 2021-03-23T00:00:00Z
[1] = 2021-03-24T00:00:00Z ?

Comment: I lose 23H at the end of the period, the last day end at 23:00, so I would like a third field

Comment: You want to include the *hours*, but you create the period with *day* intervals. What you're looking for is custom logic that should perhaps be handled through an array of dates instead of a period object. Or, a period object with an hour interval (that would yield 47 entries, though).

Comment: This is how DatePeriod works. It only will give you full, complete periods. If you want "1 day" periods, it's not going to give you a 1 hour answer. After you loop through the dates it provides, you can check to see if `$period->getEndDate() > $period->last()` and add that yourself.

Comment: I already tried to make the interval in minuted, but it will always truncate it in days.

Comment: Can you show how you tried to use it?

Comment: There should be an option on Carbon to accomplish this, it can be useful for many use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that's how it's intended to work. If you want to include that last date that doesn't amount to a full period, you'll have to add it on your own.

#### Including '2021-03-24T23:00:00Z' at the end.

```php
$start = '2021-03-23T00:00:00Z';
$end = '2021-03-24T23:00:00Z';

$period = (new Carbon($start))->toPeriod($end); // default period is +1d

$periodArray = $period->toArray();
if (!last($periodArray)->is($end)) {
    $periodArray[] = new Carbon($end);
}
```

Last lines can be converted into a single statement with `tap()`

```php
$periodArray = tap($period->toArray(), function(&$array) use ($end) {
    if (!last($array)->is($end)) {
        $array[] = new Carbon($end);
    }
});
```

#### Including '2021-03-25T00:00:00Z' at the end

```php
$start = '2021-03-23T00:00:00Z';
$end = '2021-03-24T23:00:00Z';

$period = (new Carbon($start))->toPeriod(
    (new Carbon($end))->startOfDay()->is($end)
        ? $end
        : (new Carbon($end))->addDays(1)
);

$periodArray = $period->toArray();
```

Comment: Ok, it is working ! Thanks mate! I understand it is working this way by design !

Comment: Cool. I added the other possibility if you want to have the next day instead

Comment: I understand this is the intended behavior, but they may be many use cases for this, so why does Carbon not allow to pass some option to make this default behavior? Such as Carbon::create($start, $days, $end, static::INCLUDE_LEFTOVER_PERIOD)